# Why am I getting Import Error in Pycharm and what is a virtualenv

Tags: python, import, pycharm, virtualenv

I created a computer vision project that has to do with camera and hand gesture recognition when I first created the project the entire code was running well and fully functional then I closed the project and tried to open it a week later and now its giving me a Long error of saying something about import error numpy and source tree or something. Below is the exact error. I am using a MacBook M1 Pro btw. Apple OS

I tried to run it again and it didn't work

```
/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/bin/python /Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/HandTrackingModule.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 10, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 8, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from numpy.__config__ import show as show_config
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__config__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 50, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy C-extensions failed. This error can happen for
many reasons, often due to issues with your setup or how NumPy was
installed.

We have compiled some common reasons and troubleshooting tips at:

    https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html

Please note and check the following:

  * The Python version is: Python3.9 from "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/bin/python"
  * The NumPy version is: "1.26.3"

and make sure that they are the versions you expect.
Please carefully study the documentation linked above for further help.

Original error was: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/HandTrackingModule.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "/Users/wali/Desktop/HandTracking/HandTrackingProject/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 135, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg) from e
ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
OpenCV bindings requires "numpy" package.
Install it via command:
    pip install numpy

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Umm, maybe try the directions specified in the traceback? (Run `pip install numpy` in your venv (aka in the PyCharm terminal)).

I mean, the traceback literally says `IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!` so, I suppose read the advice?

Also, have a read of what a virtual environment is [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), I'm not personally that well versed.

Let me know if you have other problems. There have been reported issues with MacOS ARM Lineup as numpy is in C (I believe), so make sure to search up any other errors you get on stackoverflow first.

Comment: I checked numpy version in my venv list and python, they all seem to line up. When I do pip install numpy, it says required numpy version is already installed. I just dont understand what the issue could be. It was running fine when I first created the project then I closed it and reopen it and now its not

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

hey guys it finally worked.

Problem: It was telling me that there was an import numpy error because it wanted a specific version of numpy  (which is 1.26.3 in my case) to be installed in my pycharm.

So if I checked through my venv packages I would see that it was already installed. So I got confused as this was contradicting. All I had to do was reinstall the package.

Solution:  pip install --force-reinstall numpy==1.26.3

Write this command in your terminal and replace the 1.26.3 with your specific numpy version that your pycharm is requesting and your project can work again!